# ORDER BY DESC LIMIT with database containing over 1000 entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-order-by

Everything was working fine, then I kept getting 999 as the last value. I'm assuming that it sees that the 9 is bigger than the 1 in 1000. I may be wrong though. However it will not return anything over 1000. The code is posted below. Any help would be great.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);

$statement = $db->prepare("select * from users where user_name = :user_name");
$statement->execute(array(':user_name' => $user)); //change send to variable
$row = $statement->fetch();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $db2 = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name_uroll, $db_username, $db_password);

//Remove $db2 prepare
$statement2 = "select * from `{$user}` ORDER BY bet_id DESC LIMIT 23";    

$bid = array();

if ($stmt = $db2->query($statement2)) //PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement on success or false on failure.
{

    //If we got a PDOStatement as a return value from PDO::Query() !!!ECHO WHILE FETCHING!!! 
    while($row2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) //This loop will keep going for as many rows as the PDOStatement returns.
    {

        $bid[] = $row2['bet_id'] ;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the column type for `bet_id` ? Make sure it's `int` & not `varchar`.

Comment: @Rikesh bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name,column_name ASC|DESC;
```

Comment: How does this answer my question?